# Prove that $\mathbf{x^b}\in \langle\mathbf{x^{a_1},...,x^{a_k}} \rangle\iff \exists j\in \{1,...,k\}:\mathbf{x^{a_j}\mid x^b} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

We want to prove the following lemma:

> ***Lemma.*** Let $K$ be a field and $I:= \langle\mathbf{x^{a_1},...,x^{a_k}}  \rangle$
>   be an ideal of the polynomial ring $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ *(which is generated by the monomials $\mathbf x^{a_i}:=x{_1}^{a_{i1}}\cdots x_n^{a_{in}},\forall i\in 1,...,k) $*, with
>   $\mathbf{a_1,...,a_k}\in \Bbb{N}^n$. Then, $$\mathbf{x^b}\in
>  \langle\mathbf{x^{a_1},...,x^{a_k}}  \rangle\iff \exists j\in
>  \{1,...,k\}:\mathbf{x^{a_j}\mid x^b} $$

***Proof.*** If $\mathbf{x^b}\in
 \langle\mathbf{x^{a_1},...,x^{a_k}}\rangle \iff \exists f_1,..,f_k\in K[x_1,...,x_n]: \mathbf{x^b}=f_1\cdot \mathbf{x^{a_1}}+\cdots+f_k\cdot \mathbf{x^{a_k}}$. *But how can we conclude the division from the second implication?*

For the opposite direction, if $$\exists j\in
 \{1,...,k\}:\mathbf{x^{a_j}\mid x^b} \iff \exists f\in K[x_1,...,x_n]:  \mathbf{x^b}=f\cdot \mathbf{x^{a_j}},\ j\in \{ 1,...,k\} \implies \mathbf{x^b}\in  \langle\mathbf{x^{a_1},...,x^{a_k}}\rangle.$$ 
*Does the last implication hold for the opposite direction?*

Thank you.

Comment: Monomials are a *basis* over $K$ for your polynomial ring.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks for your comment. If $\mathbb{T}^n:=\{\text{the set of all monomials over K} \}$, then $K[x_1,...,x_n]=\langle \mathbb{T}^n \rangle$. And now?

Comment: Give it some thought, Chris. :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the equality
$$x^b = f_1 x^{a_1} + \cdots + f_n x^{a_n}$$
(I won't bother putting the bold font), you know that $x^b$ must occur as a monomial in the expression
$$f_1 x^{a_1} + \cdots + f_n x^{a_n}.$$
But all monomials in this expression occur as multiples of some $x^{a_i}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I face difficulty in your last sentence. Could you please explain?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a monomial and $f$ is a polynomial then all the monomials in $\mu f $ are divisible by $\mu$. Therefore, if $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n$ are monomials and $f_1, \dots , f_n$ are polynomials then all the monomials in $mu_1 f_1 + \cdots + \mu_n f_n$ are divisible by $\mu_i$ for some $i$. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I apologize for the late answer. Why $mu_1 f_1$ and not $\mu_1$?

Comment: Sorry you are right. Forgot the backlash

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\mathbf{x^b}=f_1\mathbf{x^{a_1}}+...+f_k\mathbf{x^{a_k}}=(\mathbf{x^{a_{11}}+x^{a_{12}}+...})\cdot \mathbf{x^{a_1}}+...+(\mathbf{x^{a_{k1}}+x^{a_{k2}}+...})\cdot\mathbf{x^{a_k}}$. So, in the RHS we have a monomial in the form $\mathbf{x^{a_{ji}}x^{a_j}}$, for some $j\in \{1,2,...,k\}$ and $i =1,2,...$ and from this, $\mathbf{x^{a_j}|x^b}$. Right?