# $ \langle lt(g_1),..., lt(g_t) \rangle = in_<(I) \implies G $ is a Grobner basis for I

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, groebner-basis

Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of the polynomial ring $S:=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ (where $K$ is a field) , which is equiped with a monomial ordering $<$, and $G:=\{g_1,...,g_t \}\subseteq I$. We want to show that:
$$ \langle lt(g_1),..., lt(g_t) \rangle = in_<(I) \implies G \text{ is a Grobner basis for I}. $$

If we take one polynomial $0_K\neq f \in I$ then from the definition $lt(f) \in in_< (I)=\langle lt(g_1),...,lt(g_t) \rangle \implies \exists h_1,...,h_t\in S: lt(f)= h_1\cdot lt(g_1) + ... + h_t \cdot lt(g_t) $. It's clear that we need to show that $lt(g_i)|lt(f),$ for some $ i \in \{1,..., t\}  $.

*All the books I have searched, compare the RHS, LHS and immediately conclude that we have the division above. But, I can not understand this step. Could you please explain it?*

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: While I don't know what means a GB for you (usually the equality of the two monomial ideals is taken as a definition), I'm pretty sure this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595009/prove-that-mathbfxb-in-langle-mathbfxa-1-xa-k-rangle-iff-exi) of yours solves the problem as I understand it.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you for your comment. I use this definition: Let $I$ be an ideal of $S$ (equiped with $<$). A set of non-zero polynomials $G:=\{g_1,...,g_t\} \subseteq I$  is a  Grobner Basis (GB) of $I$, if $\forall f \in I \backslash \{0_K\}, \exists i \in \{1,...,t\}: lm(g_i)|lm(f)$. Yes, indeed, but I would prefer, to be explained more here, in this question. Could you please explain it?